# Trigger to Create User in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Well, after insert a user in systemuser, i like to create a ROLE for PostgreSQL, using the password of new user. But when i try create the user, this error appears:

> Blockquote
>   ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW"
>   LINE 24:   ALTER USER NEW.login ENCRYPTED PASSWORD NEW.password...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_insertuser() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trg_insertuser$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        DROP USER OLD.login;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        ALTER USER OLD.login ENCRYPTED PASSWORD NEW.password;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN       
        CREATE USER NEW.login ENCRYPTED PASSWORD NEW.password CREATEDB IN GROUP group_user;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$trg_insertuser$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What's happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `execute`.

```
execute 'drop user ' || quote_ident(OLD.login);
```

etc...